# Visual Studio project not building when I click debug or press F5

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

VS2010 c#, winforms project.

It does not build automatically when I click on debug or press f5. If I manually build the project before I debug, it compiles and changes are picked up.

My other projects all work as expected. Why doesn't it build automatically?

Comment: Does anything happen at all? Is there any entry in the output window?

Answer (score 114):

Right-click the Solution (not project) in the Solution Explorer and select Configuration Manager.  Check if Build is turn off for the current configuration.

Comment: Even though my build option was turned on I unchecked it and checked it again ..The F5 started working ! weird.

Comment: I think changing platform (Any CPU, x86..) somehow turned off Build.

Answer (score 49):

Check your settings in Tools->Options.

Go to the projects and Solutions area, Build and Run page.

There is a setting "On Run, when projects are out of date:" Make sure this is set to 'Always build.'

[image]

Answer (score 15):

I ran into this same issue and I did the following:

1. Run Build Clean
2. Close the solution
3. Delete any .suo and .user settings files
4. Delete any .ncb files
5. Open the solution again
6. Unload the project
7. Reload the project
8. Make sure the project is set as startup again
9. Debug away!

You may be able to only do steps 6-9 but I don't know how to get back in that state.

Comment: I didn't have any .suo , .user or .ncb files but unloading and reloading the project made it magically work. THANKS!

Comment: Cleaning worked for me. I also closed and reopened solution, so steps 1 and 2. So strange.

Answer (score 6):

## When you work on a dependency

In my case, I am working on a library used by an executable.
It was necessary to say to the solution to include the dependency of the library in the executable project solution to build the executable code and the library code before launching the debugging:

- Tools Menu, click on Options. Go to "Projects and Solutions/Build and Run", "On Run, when projects are out of date" needs to be on "Always build".
- Right-click the Solution (not project) in the Solution Explorer and select "Project Dependencies". Check the boxes of dependencies "Lib1" and "Lib2".

Comment: This is what im looking for..Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Because my project was independend from other projects by using prism I had to uncheck 'Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run' in Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Build and Run.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case someone else runs into the same problem as I did: for me it turned out to be a setting in my web.config as follows:

```
<httpRuntime fcnMode="Disabled" targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="40960" executionTimeout="1200" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

What this guy does is he disables File Change Notification, which is used to restart the application domain when a change is detected in critical files e.g. anything in the bin or .config files. Without fcn, I would make code changes, press F5 and still see the old code, and all breakpoints would be whited out because the source was different to what IISExpress was serving up.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation with multiple projects in a solution in Visual Studio 2013.  One of the projects that the Startup project uses was not building when I clicked the Run button.  I had to right-click on the Startup project and select "Build Dependencies" and check the project that wasn't building in there.

Answer (score 0):

Was scratching my head on this for a while, turns out our office's Folder Redirection configuration (e.g. My Documents to point to a Network location) did not integrate well with VS.