# Visual Studio Does not notice code changes

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm currently working on a WPF project in visual studio but I have the problem that when I press <kbd>F5</kbd> my it does not build my code it just runs the previous build. It seems like Visual Studio ignores the fact that I change my code.
Luckily pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> builds the solution but it's annoying when you press <kbd>F5</kbd> by mistake and expect it to build and it doesn't.
I have Checked the **"Options->Project and Solutions->Build and Run->On Run"** and it is set to always build and **"Build"** is checked for my project in the build configuration manager.

Comment: Go to Build->Configuration Manager and make sure all your projects are marked as "Build" for your Active solution platform.

Comment: I have and all projects have "Build" set

Comment: Tried this steps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660871/visual-studio-project-not-building-when-i-click-debug-or-press-f5